# AngularJS extend service using factory and get extended scope

Tags: angularjs

I want to extend a service to override some method and add some method too.

But, I can not get a scope in child service. I think the parent service is not injected to child class as well, I mean it seems like just an object, not instance.

Here is my example,

Parent service,

```
export class ParentService implements IModalMixin {
    constructor(modalMixin: IModalMixin,
        private _: _.LoDashStatic) {
    }

    doSomething() {}

    parentMethod() {
        return 'Okay';
    }
}
```

Child service,

```
/* @ngInject */
export function childServiceFactory(ParentService: any) {
    var extended = angular.extend(ParentService, {});

    // override parent method
    extended.doSomething = () => {
        return this.parentMethod(); // error this.parentMethod is not a function
    }

    return extended;
}
```

// and load to module

```
module
.service('ParentService', MyService)
.factory('ChildService', childServiceFactory)
```

Please advise me what I'm doing wrong?

My angular version is 1.4.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use arrow function in this case, otherwise context `this` is not `extended` object.

Normal function would work:

```
/* @ngInject */
export function childServiceFactory(ParentService: any) {
    var extended = angular.extend(ParentService, {});

    // override parent method
    extended.doSomething = function () {
        return this.parentMethod();
    }

    return extended;
}
```